# SET spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps & date-format to ISO1806 globally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I know, there are several similar questions about that problem but I cant find any satisfying solution. Thats why I would like to **reopen** it here.

- I want to set the `JSON serialization` of `Dates (java.util)` in `SpringBoot` to `ISO1806` format globally.

I tried:

add dependecy:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda`

**set property**:

`spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` e.g.

-didnt work. Still TimeStamps

Also tried some other solutions but they didnt work or were deprecated or hacked etc...

- So how to solve it correctly with current state?

*side note:*
I cant user `@JsonFormat()` annotation since the classes are generated by **older systems** which I cant access right now. Thats why I seek for a **global solution**. Anyway a global soultion seems to be a logical one.

Hope someone can help. 
Thanks in advance for any hints.

Kind Regards

Gregor

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Serialization. Just add this bean in your configuration class and write serialization class as per your requirement.

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Date.class, new CustomDateSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        builder.configure(objectMapper);
        return builder;
    }
```

Serializer class:

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        String date = null;//parse here as per your requirement.
        gen.writeString(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess that would work, but isnt it a bit hardcore solution for the given requirement? - I ll try it anyway :)

Comment: But NO, it doesnt work for me. Even with ´mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false); ´
The Bean is created, but not triggerd on serialization.

Comment: are you sure? there is no call in CustomDeSerializer class in serialize method?

Comment: if your pojo has util.Date.class then must be call serialize method if you import here util.Date

Comment: you can check import util.Date or sql.Date

Comment: Its util.Date - Thats whats confusing me too right now. The serilize method is not called. I must have some errors in it. I ll check it and report back. Thanks+!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.